# Inner classes inside a instance method

Tags: java

I have seen an unusual occurrence. Please help me how to instantiate a class which is written inside a method. The below program compiled successfully in Netbeans

```
  class OuterClass
    {
      int instanceVar;
      void InstanceMethod()
       {
          class InnerClass
           {
             int innerClassVar;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: So, what don't you understand? It's like an anonymous inner class, except it's not anonymous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just do it like any other object:

```
class OuterClass
{
  int instanceVar;
  void InstanceMethod()
   {
      class InnerClass
       {
         int innerClassVar;
       }

       //...

       InnerClass myInstance = new InnerClass();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add: These are called [Local Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html). You instantiate them like "normal" classes in your method, as pointed out in [morgano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844493/1153530)

Answer (score 1):

Can only be used inside the method, and most often should be a static class.

Comment: I didnt analyzed it. Now I got the answer. It is a local class hence it must and should be instantiated in the same method itself, which i guess wont be used anywhere in programming.